# Unable to log in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2017

I get this error while I'm trying to login to Visual Studio 2017:

> Impossible to load IEFRAME DLL

[image]

Answer (score 0):

SOVLED! There is some bug (unknown) with the sign in option presented in the top right corner of the Visual Studio window. As part of opening this issue, I was directed to report this problem via Visual Studio>Help>Send Feedback>Report a problem. This openes a new instance of "Visual Studio Feedback" which required that I log in. Funny enough, it let me sign in via this interface. When I went back to Visual Studio proper, I was signed in!!! Major bug. Please fix.
Via: [source](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/70622/unable-to-login-into-visual-studio-2017-with-micro.html)